Device for conferencing in Cold Storage
What is a cost effective way of doing conferencing in a cold storage? The challenge that I'm currently facing are bad network, long latency, delayed respond, and low quality of video.

How are you currently connecting? WiFi to an AP outside the cold storage? The most obvious solution is to bring an Ethernet cable inside the cold storage (and power, but you probably already have that, or it could use PoE) and install a WiFi AP (or several depending on the size and/or layout) inside the cold storage…

@jacron currently using a modem router with a card that run 4G network. How do you connect to the device when using a Ethernet cable? Need a router inside?

If you want to connect your device directly via Ethernet you just need an Ethernet cable brought inside.
